# Make bin field mandatory in inventory detail window

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I need to make the 'bin' field mandatory within the inventory detail sublist on item receipt, presently it allows the users to leave the bin field blank. I am relatively new to scripting. Can anyone please advice on how to achieve this? Thanks[image]

Comment: Have you considered setting the "Use preferred bin on item receipts" (Accounting Preferences), and setting a preferred bin on your items ? This will help the item receipt process by freeing the person doing the receipt from having to identify the correct bin first ?

Answer (score 0):

Bins can be made mandatory on all transactions *except* Item Receipts in the Setup > Accounting > Accounting Preferences > Items/Inventory, and as Simon Delicata mentioned in the comments, there is also an option to use preferred bins on items receipts:

Setup > Accounting > Accounting Preferences > Items/Inventory "use preferred bins on item receipts".

> When you enable this preference, the Bin field on item receipts defaults to the preferred bin instead of leaving the field blank.
> Disable this preference if you prefer the Bin field to remain blank by default.

Of course, this would require ensuring all bins have a preferred bin up front.

If you don't want to go that route, another possible solution for you is a workflow or script that checks each item in "Before Submit" and if that item has "Use Bins" checked on it's record but the bin field is empty, you can prevent submission of the receipt. <s>with an alert to the user. If using SuiteScript 2.0, the N/ui module exposes native alert elements (dialogs, banner messages, etc.)</s>

Edit: I was mistaken, if you want to use the N/ui module messages/dialogs you'd need to use a client script.